# Query to get data from three tables (Categories,Sub_Categories,Sub_Categories_three) and show it on view

Tags: php, mysql

I have Three Table

categories

```
id
name
```

Sub_Categories

```
id
name
category_id
```

Sub_categories_three

```
id
name
sub_categories
```

now I want to show all the data(name) from these table in the dropdown list, what would be the query to do so and how to set them on a view(nested loop) using foreach or mysqli_fetch_assoc().

I use this query

```
$query="SELECT a.c_name,a.id, b.sc_name,b.id ,c.sct_name,c.id 
FROM categories a 
right JOIN sub_categories b ON a.id=b.id 
right JOIN sub_categories_three c ON b.id=c.id ";
```

but this Query is returning null values also that fill unnecessary space in my dropdown  tag.

Here is function code

```
public function category(){

    $query="?";

    $conn=$this->Connection();
    $result = mysqli_query($conn,$query);

    $num_rows = mysqli_num_rows($result);


        if ($num_rows>0) {
            return $result;
        }

    }
```

Here is index.php Code

```
<select name="category_id">
<?php $result = $obj->category();
while ($row=mysqli_fetch_array($result)) { ?>

<option><?php echo $row['name'] ?></option>
<?php } ?>
</select>
```

Answer (score 0):

Use joins to get the combination of tables.
I would say out of the top of my head something like this:

```
$query = "SELECT categories.name, subcategories.name, subcategoriesthree.name FROM categories INNER JOIN sub_categories ON categories.category_id= subcategories.subcategory_id AS result1 INNER JOIN sub_categories three ON result1.subcategory_id = sub_category_three.id
```

I think that should do it.

For more information about joins, see: https://www.w3schools.com/sql/sql_join.asp

Comment: Ah my bad, sorry. You should do INNER JOIN 'table-name' AS 'alias' ON 'value = value'

Answer (score 0):

You can use an SQL INNER JOIN to fetch the data in the three tables.
So, the answer would be:
`$query = "SELECT a.name AS Name, b.name AS CategoryName, c.name AS SubcategoryName
         FROM categories a
         INNER JOIN Sub_Categories b ON a.id=b.id
         INNER JOIN Sub_Categories_three ON b.id=c.id"`

Comment: by this query im only getting 3 main category and also 3 sub and sub_three categories, but i want all the categories,sub_categories and sub_categories_three to show in index page

Comment: i use this query `$query="SELECT a.c_name,a.id, b.sc_name,b.id ,c.sct_name,c.id FROM categories a 
                 right JOIN sub_categories b ON a.id=b.id
                  right JOIN sub_categories_three c ON b.id=c.id  ";` but i return null values also that i dont want.